# Is it okay for me to violate my school's honor policy by ghostwriting others' papers for money?

Tags: ethics, plagiarism, cheating

I've been asked to write a paper for someone else at my school and it has made me question whether I'd be doing a horrible thing by agreeing. I have done it and accepted pay before now. My papers are generally relatively good. A sizeable portion of my income in high school came from papers I had written for others.

I've written fewer things for people in college. My clientele has, to this point, consisted of old friends and friends of friends from the nearby community colleges and stuff. These essays take more than the fifty minutes to churn out than high school ones did, but they also feel more rewarding because I usually have to research and learn a bit before asking for a bit of a higher payment than I charged in high school. This whole thing didn't really feel morally unwholesome until a person at my college asked me to write an essay for her the other day.

We have an honor code that I thought worked well. While I wouldn't be breaking a rule by giving someone my intellectual property, the idea that they'd be signing the same agreement I always do about adhering to the school's policies on a piece written by me really freaks me out! Luckily it's nothing that would be published in any way, but it still opened me to what I guess is a common enough ethical dilemma. Do I sell out or do I pay attention to the "right" thing to do?

I have no scruples making people from other places pay. I'd still write a paper for a high schooler at the drop of their pretty penny. Doing it for someone here just feels perverse. I'm also gunning for a job as writing tutor --a flawed position in a crumbling part of the institution in which I'm still super interested. Right now it seems as though I'm teetering between becoming either the helper of or the worker for others.

Personal values aside it would probably be super awkward tutoring some people and doing the work for others, particularly if one of the professors who has recommended me for the tutor position were to discover that I had written papers for students taking their class. I imagine I'd be fired.

Still, writing papers pays well enough. This person has essentially agreed to pay by the page at a rate based on the grade the paper earns. Right now I'm expecting at least $100 for five or six hours of work, which is significantly more than any job I can get working for the school. She also indicated that she'd be interested in pursuing my services further should the first paper prove satisfactory. I could be making a decent bit of coin by doing something I actually enjoy while learning and developing is I wouldn't necessarily entertain under certain circumstances.

Do the many ethical implications necessarily outweigh the high potential monetary gains? Should it matter to me when I'm technically doing nothing wrong (apart from subverting some classic pedagogic practices and participating in small-scale soul sale among other issues)? Isn't this basically what professional speech writers do? Assuming I stop, where should I draw the line (i.e. should I stop writing for others entirely, or what)?

Can you think of any other comments, questions, or concerns for me to address?

Comment: Let me just point out that "it has been a long night; I'm too lazy to search and interpret other people's somewhat similar situations" is never the right attitude if you expect others to spend their time answering your questions.

Comment: I am wondering. If you have no compunction, then you'd just go and do what aids your wallet and try not to be caught. I'd have an opinion on that, but this is just mine, and SE is not a court and I am not a judge. But you seem to be bothered by it. So, clearly, you feel that it is wrong to do so. On the other hand, you talk about "subverting classic pedagogy", as if it is a program of subversion you run, almost robin-hooding what you do. To me it feels that you haven't decided what category you see yourself in. Cont'd

Comment: It's impossible to answer your first question of "Do the many ethical implications necessarily outweigh the high potential monetary gains?" Some people will gladly sell their soul for a dollar, while others wouldn't enter an ethical grey zone for a much larger sum.

Comment: However: as long as there is assessment, you deprive honest students from their well earned kudos (i.e. grade) for their honest work and give dishonest students the opportunity to buy themselves kudos for money. Since academic achievements are not - unlike money - supposed to be freely exchangeable, but are supposed to be tied to personas, you are cheating at least the university, the honest students and the employers of both types of students (and possibly others). You seem to see the problem or you wouldn't be here. So, what do you want to really know?

Comment: Are you paying taxes on that money?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, sorry about the rudeness. I was pushing a 48 hour day and just wanted answers fast. I do intend to look more closely into others' cases after I've finally had sleep.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, before being asked by a person from my school I truly did have very few scruples about all this. I think I over complicated my question because of the ambivalence I was feeling this morning about myself. The idea of allowing people to plagiarize my work on my campus put stuff into a negative perspective that has brought the rest of the issue into clarity. Not sure why I posted exactly, except that it felt more suitable to have someone else process what I was beginning to realize than to spend the resources to do it on my own at that time.

Comment: @Daniel, all income is taxable income.

Comment: Please spend less time defending yourself and more time researching and writing a properly posed question. // How exactly would you report this income on your tax return?

Comment: How does this help the other student progress in her studies?

Comment: @Pi_Arc "it felt more suitable to have someone else process what I was beginning to realize than to spend the resources to do it on my own at that time" - I am not sure I like the message of this sentence. Parse it again: "*I* have a problem; have somebody else use *their* resources to solve *my* problem rather than use *mine* to solve it." - did you really mean to say this? The message gets more and more murky. Get a good night's sleep and revisit.

Comment: I agree with @Morgan: the question is asking whether it is honorable to do something dishonorable.  Clearly not.  Maybe the OP doesn't understand why lying, cheating and getting paid for it are dishonorable things in an academic context, but I don't think this site is the right place for such "remedial ethics."

Comment: I actually think you would do better to ask your question here, regarding the ethical 'dilemma' you are facing... http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Gary: I don't think "Should I behave ethically or un-?" is an ethical dilemma.  However, I agree that "Why -- or in what sense -- *should* I behave ethically?" is a good philosophical question.  As with most good philosophical questions, one struggles with them for their inherit interest, not because of the practical benefits one expects...

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Well we are now in the amorphous realm of philosophy I fear. Your premise appears to be that the student is acting unethically here, no doubt because their actions fall outside of the scope of what you would call ethically correct behavior? I think the OP needs to figure out what their own ethical parameters are, ("Do the many ethical implications necessarily outweigh the high potential monetary gains?") and the philosophers might be able to help him/her do that better than anyone here was the idea I was toying with when I coined the above comment.

Comment: @Gary: It's not a question of what I call ethically correct behavior.   "I think the OP needs to figure out what their own ethical parameters are" If you mean that the OP needs to figure out whether s/he is willing to abide by the standard ethics of academia: yes.  But again: "Should I behave ethically or unethically?" is a trivial ethical question, as is "Do the many ethical implications necessarily outweigh the high potential monetary gains?" No academic is going to tell the OP that it is "OK" to violate the standard ethics of academia: this follows directly from the meanings of the words.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark "No academic is going to tell the OP that it is "OK" to violate the standard ethics of academia: this follows directly from the meanings of the words". Hence my suggestion they take their question to philosophy for a more balanced discussion, this was also in my mind when I made the original suggestion. It was made semi tongue-in-cheek at the time, but certainly there's definite merit for the OP to ask the question in philosophy for the very reason you've just articulated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be subtle trolling, as the OP clearly understands that what they are doing is incorrect and is simply looking for moral justification to perform the service anyways.

Comment: You should read Chapter 9 of The Pale King by David Foster Wallace.

Answer (score 12):

You are aiding others in breaking the rules of their college. Indeed, my old university, Texas A&M, had the Aggie Honor Code that says:

> An Aggie does not lie, cheat or steal or tolerate those who do.

Note the second part. While it may not be illegal from the perspective of the law, you are helping others lie and cheat. Don't do it, you're going to regret it in hindsight as you go through life and gain more of an appreciation why academic dishonesty is a problem.

But see it from a positive perspective: You are good at writing. There are businesses that are looking for people like you. For example, there are companies that specialize in editing other people's works -- e.g., editing scientific papers for people who are either not good writers, or whose first language is not English. There is a market for your skill set, and one where you can actually make a living doing the ethically right thing. Most universities also have writing centers that keep a list of people who are interested in helping foreign students edit their theses and similar things. All of these will be rewarding jobs where you learn something and can help others without moral dilemmas.

Comment: I should note that there is a level of specialization required to work with non-native speakers (of any language). There are quite a few more complications, and it's not just about *editing* their content, but rather providing iterations on their work where editing for grammar, spelling, etc. is the lowest-order concern. If wanting to edit professionally, you *must* know your audience.

Comment: Sure, no doubt. All I meant is to point out that if you're good at writing, there are directions you can take this in to make a living.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is no. Don't do it. The other person is committing plagiarism and you would be at fault as well, even though it is your work, because you essentially helped them plagiarize. Everything you asked points to you feeling guilty, so go with your gut. This could get very messy and you could be expelled. Where to draw the line? Don't do other people's homework. Period.

Not that I needed to find references to your question, but here's an [article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/gina-ciliberto/college-homework-essay-writing-services_b_5840080.html).

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably just going to stop altogether. It just doesn't feel right anymore.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd still write a paper for a high schooler at the drop of their pretty penny.

And yet, those high schoolers are the ones you're damaging the most.

This is what I tell some of my younger relatives. For every homework that you do not do now, that same kind of work will become ten times harder once you're in college.

> Isn't this basically what professional speech writers do?

Professional speech writers can say what they do and who they've worked for on their resume. Will you be able to do the same?

Also, by getting in the habit of letting others take the credit for your work, you're actually devaluing yourself.

> Assuming I stop, where should I draw the line (i.e. should I stop
>   writing for others entirely, or what)?

You already know where that line should be drawn. Writing for others teaches them absolutely nothing.

The next time you speak with this person (or someone else who wants your services), tell them that you won't write the essay for them, but that you'll be glad to lock yourself in a room with them for five hours to make sure they write their essay.

And then, you set your ground rules and ask them for the full cash payment in advance.

Your ground rules can vary, but I would personally include: Cell phones turned off. No wifi (unless research is required). This is a one-on-one session. They should sit next to you so you see what they're writing. No distraction (except for restroom breaks), unless they want you to walk out of that room and keep the remaining balance of the payment. The same goes if they're late or miss an appointment, you keep the money if that happens. And they should come to you at least three days before an essay is due otherwise your hourly rate is double.

The idea is that they wouldn't just be hiring a tutor, they would be hiring a task master. And even though, they may not be able to finish their essay in 5 hours, the work they accomplish in that time may motivate them enough to actually finish the work on their own.